# Chance of 2 cars hitting each other

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

I'm preparing for a statistics test next week and we got some supplementary exercises without solution. Now I'm stuck trying to solve one of these. I couldn't find similar exercises on Google and we haven't made any exercise that resembles this one in class.

> The braking distance X and Y of two cars are independent and normally distributed. At a speed of 50km/h it applies that $\mu_x=27m$, $\sigma_x^2=35m^2$, $\mu_y=37m$ and $\sigma_x^2=65m^2$. Suppose both cars drive towards each other and brake when they are only 70m apart. What's the probability of both cars not hitting each other?

Now I think I have to calculate the chance $P(X <= Y - 70)$? But I'm not really sure on how to continue? It's not clear to me how I can calculate this chance given that X and Y are not constants, but variables that follow some distribution.

I'm not asking for a complete solution. Maybe just a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Start by checking that $X\leq Y-70$ is really the condition for the cars' not crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cars do not crash when $X+Y < 70$. Since $X$ and $Y$ are normaly distributed and independent, $X+Y$ also follows normal distribution with mean $\mu_x+\mu_y$ and variance $\sigma^2_x+\sigma^2_y$

So, you just need to calculate $P(Z<70)$ with $Z\sim N(64, 100)$.

Comment: Nice answer (+1) but do note that we treat bookwork a bit differently to other questions, & try to avoid giving away too much at once. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Comment: @Scortchi: I'm sorry, I'm newbie here.

Comment: No problem - we've all done it. The site's not really set up for guiding someone to an answer through a series of hints, but you can use comments, or start by writing a partial answer that you can add more info. to as you go along. "Spoiler" format is also useful sometimes - see https://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help.